# How to access soap response dynamically from HP UFT using custom code

Tags: c#, testing, automation, xml-parsing, uft-api

I am pretty new to HP UFT and C#.

I am testing soap services. I want to dynamically parse my response xml and do some validations on it.

But to start with, I do not know how to get my response xml in to a string/xml file. I have tried and failed

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

To get the XML response into a string and file add a "Custom Code" box to the Test Flow diagram.  Create an Execute Event for the custom code.  Add an input parameter with the Type as String.  Link the input parameter to the output of the web service. In the Execute Event function add the following code.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(this.codeActivity6.Input.inputParameterName;
```

The code activity 6 is what the program assigns to the custom code box so it could be different depending on when you add the box. Now you can parse the XmlDoc.